# PHP echo \u2713 on cli is empty?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm trying to echo `"\u2713"` with PHP on the cli but I just get an empty string?

My script is

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?php

    echo "\u2713";
```

And I just get an empty string, I have the same problem with colouring the output using `"\033[31m"` Am I missing something?

Comment: are you sure that your command line interface can render unicode characters? mine can't, for example, at least not properly.

Comment: It can, I have the exact same output in a Node application of mine and it works a charm.

Comment: I've tried closing it but it makes no difference, I've even tried to use `php -a` and output it that way but just empty strings.

Comment: This should output exactly "\u2713". `"\uXXXX"` doesn't mean anything in PHP.

Comment: Okay, so the character I want to output "✓" in PHP how would I do that if it's not using an escape character? I just get a BOM if I use it "as-is"

Comment: `echo "\xE2\x9C\x93";` or `echo '✓';` if you save the file in UTF-8.

Comment: Okay, using `\xE2\x9C\x93` worked great. What about colouring? Where I'd usually use `\x1b[31m` to make the output red, what flavour does PHP use? What am I looking for on Google I should ask?

Comment: Also, could you put it as an answer so I can mark it as resolved?

Comment: It isn't PHP that renders CLI output in colour, it's the CLI shell; so you should only need to send the appropriate CSI sequences that your shell recognises

Answer (score 0):

If this works on your command line, then you should be good to go...

php -r 'echo "\xE2\x9C\x93\n";'

✓